# File `bidi.sty' not found

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

I use polyglossia with XeLaTeX on texlive. When I try to run Hebrew documents (according to [this page](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/20/hebrew-with-xetex-example/) from the Culmus project documentation) I get the following message:

> LaTeX Error: File `bidi.sty' not found.

I only recently converted to Linux and texlive and can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: `tlmgr install bidi`  should install it if you don't have it already

Comment: Just in case: Did you install `texlive` from your package manager?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried doing so, and got this:

(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/user/texmf!
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/user/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 6424.

Comment: @ABN263 so you have the debian texlive rather than the upstream one, I think that should work on new enough systems but in any case you can update/install bidi via your debian package manager `apt-get` or whatever you use.  T]he debian packages will be larger "collections" though so I do not know what name you will need to pass to apt-get but checking the debian repositories should show this, or a debian user may pass by here and answer.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using Debian's packages for TeXLive, you need to install the package which contains `bidi.sty`. You can [search](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bidi.sty&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) for a file at [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org). If you do this, you will find that `bidi.sty` is in the `texlive-lang-arabic` package. So all you need to do is run:

```
apt-get install texlive-lang-arabic
```

Comment: If somebody from other distros has this problem: same with Ubuntu and Gentoo Linux. For Hebrew you need `texlive-langother` for language formats and fonts AND `texlive-langarabic` for `bidi.sty`. See this older [Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-lang/+bug/1413808).

Comment: For Arch Linux it the package name is `texlive-langextra`.